# Unix command to copy text a specific COLUMNS from 3 files to a specific COLUMNS in a fourth file

Tags: bash, awk, sed, cut

I have 3 files, I want to copy specific COLUMNS of each file into different COLUMNS in another a fourth file. 
It's a bit tricky so follow me if possible.

```
File 1 copy COLUMNS 1,2,3,4,5 to COLUMNS 6,10,12,13,20 file 4 
File 2 copy COLUMNS 1,2,3,4,5 to COLUMNS 4,24,25,26,27 file 4
File 3 copy COLUMNS 1-9 to COLUMNS 1-3 and 14-19 to file 4
```

I have tried a couple of different things ie sed, cut, join, paste, and awk. I am able to copy the text, just not to the desired COLUMNS.

paste -d ',' file1.csv file2.csv file3.csv | sed 's/\r//g' | cut -d ',' -f 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20 | sed 's/$/\r/' >>file4.csv

Comment: Do you mean row or column/field?

Comment: So my answer should work for you ;)

Comment: Yeah, I was meaning to say COLUMN. Sorry for the confusion.
I am trying to copy specific COLUMNS of 3 files to specific COLUMNS in a fourth file.
Example:
COLUMNS 1,2,3,4 of file1 to COLUMN 8,5,6,7 in file4
COLUMNS 1,2,3,4 of file2 to COLUMN 28,25,26,27 in file4
COLUMNS 1,2,3,4 of file3 to COLUMN 18,15,16,17 in file4

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk for ARGIND:

```
awk -v OFS='\n' '
{ a[ARGIND,FNR] = $0 }
END { print a[3,1],a[3,2],a[3,3],a[2,1],a[3,4],a[1,1],... }
' file1 file2 file3 > file4
```

Given your change in requirements to want columns (fields) instead of rows (records/lines) and assuming your files contain comma-separated fields as the `paste` command you posted in your question implies, again using GNU awk for ARGIND:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
ARGIND < 3 { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[ARGIND,i]=$i; next }
{ print $1, $2, a[1,3], a[1,4], a[2,5], a[2,6], $7, $8, a[1,9] }

$ cat file1
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i

$ cat file2
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

$ cat file3
A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I

$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2 file3
A,B,c,d,5,6,G,H,i
```

If your awk doesn't provide ARGIND you can get around it by simply adding:

```
FNR == 1 { ++ARGIND }
```

if you never have empty files. If you do have empty files then you need:

```
FNR == 1 { for (i=1;i in ARGV;i++) if (ARGV[i] == FILENAME) ARGIND = i }
```

if you never have the same file name repeated. If you CAN have empty files AND repeated file names, then you need to add an array of counters for each file name, and if you can have variables set in the arg list then all of that is left as an exercise or better yet - get gawk!

Comment: I was meaning to say COLUMN. SORRY for the confusion. I am trying to copy specific COLUMNS of 3 files to specific COLUMNS in a fourth file.  Example:   COLUMNS 1,2,3,4 of file1 to COLUMN 8,5,6,7 in file4    COLUMNS 1,2,3,4 of file2 to COLUMN 28,25,26,27 in file4 COLUMNS 1,2,3,4 of file3 to COLUMN 18,15,16,17 in file4

Comment: I just updated my answer to work for columns instead of rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well, you meant field instead of row, if so check ftable [here](https://github.com/tlopo/ftable):

I didn't quite get the order of the columns you want so I will give an example of how it works.

Say we have a 3 file which look like:

File1:

```
F1_A1,F1_B1,F1_C1,F1_D1,F1_E1,
F1_A2,F1_B2,F1_C2,F1_D2,F1_E2,
F1_A3,F1_B3,F1_C3,F1_D3,F1_E3,
F1_A4,F1_B4,F1_C4,F1_D4,F1_E4,
F1_A5,F1_B5,F1_C5,F1_D5,F1_E5,
F1_A6,F1_B6,F1_C6,F1_D6,F1_E6,
F1_A7,F1_B7,F1_C7,F1_D7,F1_E7,
F1_A8,F1_B8,F1_C8,F1_D8,F1_E8,
F1_A9,F1_B9,F1_C9,F1_D9,F1_E9,
F1_A10,F1_B10,F1_C10,F1_D10,F1_E10,
```

file2:

```
F2_A1,F2_B1,F2_C1,F2_D1,F2_E1,
F2_A2,F2_B2,F2_C2,F2_D2,F2_E2,
F2_A3,F2_B3,F2_C3,F2_D3,F2_E3,
F2_A4,F2_B4,F2_C4,F2_D4,F2_E4,
F2_A5,F2_B5,F2_C5,F2_D5,F2_E5,
F2_A6,F2_B6,F2_C6,F2_D6,F2_E6,
F2_A7,F2_B7,F2_C7,F2_D7,F2_E7,
F2_A8,F2_B8,F2_C8,F2_D8,F2_E8,
F2_A9,F2_B9,F2_C9,F2_D9,F2_E9,
F2_A10,F2_B10,F2_C10,F2_D10,F2_E10,
```

file3:

```
F3_A1,F3_B1,F3_C1,F3_D1,F3_E1,
F3_A2,F3_B2,F3_C2,F3_D2,F3_E2,
F3_A3,F3_B3,F3_C3,F3_D3,F3_E3,
F3_A4,F3_B4,F3_C4,F3_D4,F3_E4,
F3_A5,F3_B5,F3_C5,F3_D5,F3_E5,
F3_A6,F3_B6,F3_C6,F3_D6,F3_E6,
F3_A7,F3_B7,F3_C7,F3_D7,F3_E7,
F3_A8,F3_B8,F3_C8,F3_D8,F3_E8,
F3_A9,F3_B9,F3_C9,F3_D9,F3_E9,
F3_A10,F3_B10,F3_C10,F3_D10,F3_E10,
```

And we want file4  to have the following map:

```
field 1     = File1(field 1)
field 2     = File2(field 1)
field 3     = File3(field 1)
field 4-7   = File1(field 2-5)
field 8-11  = File2(field 2-5)
filed 12-15 = File3(field 2-5)
```

We paste all 3 files together and pick the fields you want with ftable:

```
paste  file1 file2 file3   | ftable  -n -p 1,6,11,2-5,7-10,12-15
  F1_A1   F2_A1   F3_A1   F1_B1   F1_C1   F1_D1   F1_E1   F2_B1   F2_C1   F2_D1   F2_E1   F3_B1   F3_C1   F3_D1   F3_E1 
  F1_A2   F2_A2   F3_A2   F1_B2   F1_C2   F1_D2   F1_E2   F2_B2   F2_C2   F2_D2   F2_E2   F3_B2   F3_C2   F3_D2   F3_E2 
  F1_A3   F2_A3   F3_A3   F1_B3   F1_C3   F1_D3   F1_E3   F2_B3   F2_C3   F2_D3   F2_E3   F3_B3   F3_C3   F3_D3   F3_E3 
  F1_A4   F2_A4   F3_A4   F1_B4   F1_C4   F1_D4   F1_E4   F2_B4   F2_C4   F2_D4   F2_E4   F3_B4   F3_C4   F3_D4   F3_E4 
  F1_A5   F2_A5   F3_A5   F1_B5   F1_C5   F1_D5   F1_E5   F2_B5   F2_C5   F2_D5   F2_E5   F3_B5   F3_C5   F3_D5   F3_E5 
  F1_A6   F2_A6   F3_A6   F1_B6   F1_C6   F1_D6   F1_E6   F2_B6   F2_C6   F2_D6   F2_E6   F3_B6   F3_C6   F3_D6   F3_E6 
  F1_A7   F2_A7   F3_A7   F1_B7   F1_C7   F1_D7   F1_E7   F2_B7   F2_C7   F2_D7   F2_E7   F3_B7   F3_C7   F3_D7   F3_E7 
  F1_A8   F2_A8   F3_A8   F1_B8   F1_C8   F1_D8   F1_E8   F2_B8   F2_C8   F2_D8   F2_E8   F3_B8   F3_C8   F3_D8   F3_E8 
  F1_A9   F2_A9   F3_A9   F1_B9   F1_C9   F1_D9   F1_E9   F2_B9   F2_C9   F2_D9   F2_E9   F3_B9   F3_C9   F3_D9   F3_E9 
 F1_A10  F2_A10  F3_A10  F1_B10  F1_C10  F1_D10  F1_E10  F2_B10  F2_C10  F2_D10  F2_E10  F3_B10  F3_C10  F3_D10  F3_E10
```

**Disclaimer**: I wrote ftable.

Answer (score -1):

make a file like below (say spfunconfig) where line number (which is not actually present in the file) will be the line number in the file4. so below example will read like 1 line in file 4 is coming from 1 line from file 3.2nd line in file4 is coming from 2nd line from file3

```
1 file3
2 file3
3 file3
1 file2
5 file3
...
...
```

Code:

```
spfun(){more "$2"|head -"$1"|tail -1>>file4;}
for i in `seq 1 1 27`
do
more spfunconfig|head -"$i"|tail -1>temp
spfun $a $b < temp
done
```